# How is the iron isotope Fe(72) generated?

Tags: nuclear-physics, isotopes

Does <sup>72</sup>Fe occur naturally? Either way, can it be produced synthetically and if so, how?

Comment: You can look this up at several sites. Search on "chart of nuclides". Here's one https://www-nds.iaea.org/relnsd/vcharthtml/VChartHTML.html

Answer (score 2):

Nuclear Wallet Cards give a half life of 150 nanoseconds for Fe-72. Such short-lived isotopes are not found in equilibrium in nature and cannot be artificially produced except in microscopic quantities.

Comment: The ENSDF data set at nndc.brookhaven.gov shows 73Co(p,2pg)72Fe as one possible path.

Comment: So how is it produced?